# Getting dirty results with ngram analyzer for highlight search

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, highlight, n-gram

Hi I am using ngram with min length 1 and max length 100 and I am fetching the document and highlight the field from document . Now when i am getting the result from ES it has some random document even with size of 10. And  relevant score of that document is also high . Can someone please let me know how to reduce the non related document from my search results. search text e.g  is "samsung inc" getting result for "ach". but when I search without any space I am getting the expected result .

I used these settings

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 101
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "ngram_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 101
    }
}
```

Search Query:

```
    {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "documentType.keyword": [
                            "School"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "paidDate": {
                            "from": "2015-05-15T15:29:50",
                            "to": "2020-12-15T15:29:50",
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "updatedDate": {
                            "from": "2015-05-15T15:29:50",
                            "to": "2020-12-15T15:29:50",
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                        "query": "walmart corp*",
                        "fields": [
                            "service^1.0",
                            "teacherName^1.0",
                            "studentTeacherId^1.0",
                            "teacherAccId^1.0",
                            "chainName^1.0",
                            "paidId^1.0",
                            "studentId^1.0",
                            "studentName^1.0",
                            "teacherId^1.0",
                            "studentAccID^1.0",
                            "status^1.0"
                        ],
                        "flags": -1,
                        "default_operator": "and",
                        "analyze_wildcard": false,
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
                        "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": [
            ""
        ],
        "post_tags": [
            ""
        ],
        "fields": {
            "paidId": {},
            "chainName": {}, 
            "teacherId": {}, 
            "teacherName": {},  
            "status": {},
            "studentId": {}, 
            "studentName": {},  
            "studentAccID": {},  
            "studentTeacherId": {}, 
            "service": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 213,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2702,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 14.807846,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "scheduler_testing_new",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "nmvnmvbmnb",
        "_score": 14.807846,
        "_source": {
          "service": "ACH",
          "teacherAccId": "ASelQvpMBJAY6FJR",
          "chainName": "AMEXB2BTEST",
          "studentId": "OBgEkzyc86C0AbwP",
          "studentAccID": "AB200gR4Pll4sptx",
          "studentTeacherId": "abc68aa1a2adfaay65asd87a6das215",
          "teacherName": "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12",
          "paidId": "nmvnmvbmnb",
          "studentName": "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12",
          "teacherId": "OSARRRzoDFEKzLMO",
          "status": "MAIL"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "service": [
            "ACH"
          ],
          "teacherName": [
            "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12"
          ],
          "studentTeacherId": [
            "abc68aa1a2adfaay65asd87a6das215"
          ],
          "teacherAccId": [
            "ASelQvpMBJAY6FJR"
          ],
          "chainName": [
            "AMEXB2BTEST"
          ],
          "paidId": [
            "PY3PHrQVe9tzZPaF"
          ],
          "studentId": [
            "OBgEkzyc86C0AbwP"
          ],
          "studentName": [
            "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12"
          ],
          "teacherId": [
            "OSARRRzoDFEKzLMO"
          ],
          "studentAccID": [
            "AB200gR4Pll4sptx"
          ],
          "status": [
            "MAIL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "scheduler_testing_new",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "PY3g1OcFiSBwQlrU",
        "_score": 14.771165,
        "_source": {
          "service": "ACH",
          "teacherAccId": "ASnv9CtYz4ubuusu",
          "chainName": "AMEXB2BTEST",
          "studentId": "OBLUaGtLn6YAvepP",
          "studentAccID": "ABpcoMUvQuIAydUA",
          "studentTeacherId": "abc68aa1a2adfaay65asd87a6das215",
          "teacherName": "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12",
          "paidId": "PY3g1OcFiSBwQlrU",
          "studentName": "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12",
          "teacherId": "OSmPsSrp2CmsFyBG",
          "status": "MAIL"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "service": [
            "ACH"
          ],
          "teacherName": [
            "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12"
          ],
          "studentTeacherId": [
            "abc68aa1a2adfaay65asd87a6das215"
          ],
          "teacherAccId": [
            "ASnv9CtYz4ubuusu"
          ],
          "chainName": [
            "AMEXB2BTEST"
          ],
          "paidId": [
            "PY3g1OcFiSBwQlrU"
          ],
          "studentId": [
            "OBLUaGtLn6YAvepP"
          ],
          "studentName": [
            "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12"
          ],
          "teacherId": [
            "OSmPsSrp2CmsFyBG"
          ],
          "studentAccID": [
            "ABpcoMUvQuIAydUA"
          ],
          "status": [
            "MAIL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "scheduler_testing_new",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "PY3gPGf0gUszaoMy",
        "_score": 14.77009,
        "_source": {
          "service": "ACH",
          "teacherAccId": "ASxdVOoDIxqdTdkx",
          "chainName": "AMEXB2BTEST",
          "studentId": "OBAFhpOkWPWVr2Ze",
          "studentAccID": "AB0Em4lwMRtYsonV",
          "studentTeacherId": "abc68aa1a2adfaay65asd87a6das215",
          "teacherName": "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12",
          "paidId": "PY3gPGf0gUszaoMy",
          "studentName": "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12",
          "teacherId": "OSrg4RqDTgPxLC1Y",
          "status": "MAIL"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "service": [
            "ACH"
          ],
          "teacherName": [
            "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12"
          ],
          "studentTeacherId": [
            "abc68aa1a2adfaay65asd87a6das215"
          ],
          "teacherAccId": [
            "ASxdVOoDIxqdTdkx"
          ],
          "chainName": [
            "AMEXB2BTEST"
          ],
          "paidId": [
            "PY3gPGf0gUszaoMy"
          ],
          "studentId": [
            "OBAFhpOkWPWVr2Ze"
          ],
          "studentName": [
            "Naga Corporatiasdfaaaon12"
          ],
          "teacherId": [
            "OSrg4RqDTgPxLC1Y"
          ],
          "studentAccID": [
            "AB0Em4lwMRtYsonV"
          ],
          "status": [
            "MAIL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "scheduler_testing_new",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "PYDgkETuAGW6wUDA",
        "_score": 14.735176,
        "_source": {
          "service": "Card",
          "teacherAccId": "",
          "chainName": "INTACCT",
          "studentId": "OBHPLgTA0h5MbEHO",
          "studentAccID": "AB2hIX9e11py5BwJ",
          "studentTeacherId": "Cardustpay033",
          "teacherName": "APPLECORP",
          "paidId": "PYDgkETuAGW6wUDA",
          "studentName": "APPLECORP",
          "teacherId": "OSgLHayuYOKXJHYd",
          "status": "MAIL"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "service": [
            "Card"
          ],
          "teacherName": [
            "APPLECORP"
          ],
          "studentTeacherId": [
            "Cardustpay033"
          ],
          "chainName": [
            "INTACCT"
          ],
          "paidId": [
            "PYDgkETuAGW6wUDA"
          ],
          "studentId": [
            "OBHPLgTA0h5MbEHO"
          ],
          "studentName": [
            "APPLECORP"
          ],
          "teacherId": [
            "OSgLHayuYOKXJHYd"
          ],
          "studentAccID": [
            "AB2hIX9e11py5BwJ"
          ],
          "status": [
            "MAIL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "scheduler_testing_new",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "PYR8DATaXD6udVE4",
        "_score": 14.718508,
        "_source": {
          "service": "Card",
          "teacherAccId": "",
          "chainName": "INTACCT",
          "studentId": "OBlNai09AyGZ1dn7",
          "studentAccID": "AB2rtgOdosvlIFKg",
          "studentTeacherId": "PCard07",
          "teacherName": "APPLECORP",
          "paidId": "PYR8DATaXD6udVE4",
          "studentName": "APPLECORP",
          "teacherId": "OSntdBaqhZLYLR39",
          "status": "MAIL"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "service": [
            "Card"
          ],
          "teacherName": [
            "APPLECORP"
          ],
          "studentTeacherId": [
            "PCard07"
          ],
          "chainName": [
            "INTACCT"
          ],
          "paidId": [
            "PYR8DATaXD6udVE4"
          ],
          "studentId": [
            "OBlNai09AyGZ1dn7"
          ],
          "studentName": [
            "APPLECORP"
          ],
          "teacherId": [
            "OSntdBaqhZLYLR39"
          ],
          "studentAccID": [
            "AB2rtgOdosvlIFKg"
          ],
          "status": [
            "MAIL"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain with some example, what unexpected result are you getting ?

Comment: Harish, can you please mention the query you are using? As ACH might be the match for the other fields. In case you are doing query on a single fields then please mention mappings too :)

Comment: @ShahrozSaleem Added search query and result

Comment: @ESCoder Added search query and result